# How to check is a number is on left side or right side of number

Tags: c#, integer, var

How to check is a number is on left side or right side of number

for example number is 2 and i want where it is on 12 and 23

which is 2 is left side on 23 and right side on 12

my code

```
class Solution
{
   public static  void Main(String[] args)
   { 
      var number =  12;
      foreach(char c in number.ToString()){
         if(c=='2'){
            Console.WriteLine(c);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What should happen if the number is on both sides (for example, 22)?

Comment: `bool isLeft = number.ToString().IndexOf("2") == 0;` -- If you have to evaluate numbers with just two digits. Or, do you actually need to determine the left/right position of a digit, in relation to another, in a longer sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code out:

```
CheckNumber(12);
CheckNumber(23);

static void CheckNumber(int number)
{
    var str = number.ToString();
    if (str[0] == '2')
        Console.WriteLine("2 is in left");
    if (str[^1] == '2')
        Console.WriteLine("2 is in right");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution
{
   public static  void Main(String[] args)
   { 
      bool isLeft = true;
      var number =  12;
      foreach(char c in number.ToString()){
         if(c=='2'){
            if(isLeft)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It's on the left.");
            }
            else 
            {
               Console.WriteLine("It's on the right");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(c);
         }
     isLeft = false;
      }
   }
}
```

EDIT:
I added proof

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NewMethod(12);
            NewMethod(23);
        }

        private static void NewMethod(int number)
        {
            bool isLeft = true;
            foreach (char c in number.ToString())
            {
                if (c == '2')
                {
                    if (isLeft)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("It's on the left.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("It's on the right");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(c);
                }
                isLeft = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Console result]

Proof un-edited version works:

[image: Proof]

Comment: not working... whether where i put '2' its always print   "It's on the left."

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific I have a unit test, that doesn't agree with you.

What do you mean "whether where I put the '2'? You are talking about change the input "number" as a number 23 instead of 12? 

When I input 23 as number, I get "it's on the the left", when I input 12 I get "it's on the right".

Comment: okay the edit code is yours working ..

Comment: I assure you, they both, are, I have tested it.
The initial submissions only response is: "it's on the right".

Comment: i can't post photo but believe in me first one code is not working

Comment: I can, and I have posted proof.